# Static var being treated as let constant?

Tags: swift, static-variables

I have a struct (someUrl) containing 3 static vars:

```
struct someUrl {
    static var keywords = String()
    static var someUrlStart = String()
    static var someUrlEnd = String()
}
```

and a class (Url) with a variable of type someUrl:

```
class Url {
    var someUrlConstructor: someUrl

    init(keywords: String, someUrlEnd: String, someUrlStart: String) {
        self.someUrlConstructor = someUrl(someUrlStart = someUrlStart, keywords = keywords, someUrlEnd = someUrlEnd)
    }

}
```

In trying to initialize the variable in the class, Xcode is throwing an error stating that someUrlStart is a let constant.

> cannot assign to value: 'someUrlStart' is a 'let' constant

This is ALL I have in my code so far, and I don't get why a static var would be treated as a constant. Is this specific to initializers?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are confusing the compiler here. First your syntax is wrong in terms of how you pass parameters, it should be `:` instead of `=`, then you should remove the `static` and change the order of the parameters:

```
struct someUrl {
    var keywords = String()
    var someUrlStart = String()
    var someUrlEnd = String()
}

class Url {
    var someUrlConstructor: someUrl

    init(keywords: String, someUrlEnd: String, someUrlStart: String) {
        self.someUrlConstructor = someUrl(keywords: keywords, someUrlStart: someUrlStart, someUrlEnd: someUrlEnd)
    }
}
```

Alternatively if you want to keep them static remove the parameters completely since now they are static variables and not member / instance variables:

```
struct someUrl {
    static var keywords = String()
    static var someUrlStart = String()
    static var someUrlEnd = String()
}

class Url {
    var someUrlConstructor: someUrl

    init(keywords: String, someUrlEnd: String, someUrlStart: String) {
        self.someUrlConstructor = someUrl()
    }
}
```

What the compiler thought you were doing (or basically what you were in fact doing writing `=`) was trying to change the `someUrlEnd` (and the other two) you were given as a initializer parameter which is in fact a constant.

---

Apart from the wrong syntax I do not see a use for the `static` or for the `class Url`, just take the `struct someUrl`, its default initializer and go from there. General note: please upper case the first letter of the struct: `SomeUrl`.

Comment: Thanks much. I had ordered the parameters the way I did because of the error. I wanted to see if it would always throw an error on the first parameter or if it was specific to someUrlStart. Also, I was intending to keep them as static vars. Thanks much for reminding me to strip the parameters

Answer (score 1):

`static` variables belong to the `struct` itself, not the the instance. So you can not reach them via the instance, using the dot notation.

Not sure what you want to do but this would work technically:

```
struct SomeUrl {
    static var keywords = String()
    static var someUrlStart = String()
    static var someUrlEnd = String()
}

class Url {
    let someUrlConstructor = SomeUrl()

    init(keywords: String, someUrlEnd: String, someUrlStart: String) {
        SomeUrl.keywords = keywords
        SomeUrl.someUrlStart = someUrlStart
        SomeUrl.someUrlEnd = someUrlEnd
    }
}
```